# .Firstpage.Rightheader command with picture does not work

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set a different header and footer with VBA for the first page of an Excel sheet that should be printed. The right header should contain a picture and the left header another picture. Those should only be displayed on the first page.

I have tried the below code but somehow the .Firstpage object leads me to an error message.

```
Sub AddFooterHeaderImage()
    
Dim ImagePath As String
Dim ImagePath2 As String
Dim Validation As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim excludeSheets As String


  ImagePath = "C:\Pictures\Picture1.png"
  ImagePath2 = "C:\Pictures\Picture2.png"
  
            
excludeSheets = "|Instructions|VCS|Import|"      
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ThisWorkbook
For Each ws In .Worksheets

If InStr(excludeSheets, "|" & ws.Name & "|") = 0 Then
  
    With ws.PageSetup
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
    .FirstPage.RightHeaderPicture.Filename = ImagePath 
    .FirstPage.RightHeader = "&G"
    .FirstPage.LeftHeaderPicture.Filename = ImagePath2
    .FirstPage.LeftHeader = "&G"
    
    
    ws.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    End With

End If
Next ws
End With
Sheets("Instructions").Select

OutPut = MsgBox("Headers & Footers added", vbInformation, "Information")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the code as below and it works.

```
Sub AddFooterHeaderImage()
'PURPOSE: Insert Image File into Spreadsheet Header or Footer on every selected worksheet


Dim ImagePath As String
Dim ImagePath2 As String
Dim Validation As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim excludeSheets As String


'Where is Image Located?
  ImagePath = "S:\desktop\xxxx.png"
  ImagePath2 = "S:\desktop\xx.png"
  
'Does the Image File Exist?
  On Error Resume Next
    Validation = Dir(ImagePath)
    Validation = Dir(ImagePath2)
  On Error GoTo 0

  If Validation = "" Then
    MsgBox "Could not locate the image file located here: " & ImagePath
    Exit Sub
  End If
      
'Add Image To Each Active Sheet
excludeSheets = "|sheetA|SheetB|SheetC|"        'The sheet names to exclude delimited by "|"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ThisWorkbook

For Each ws In .Worksheets

If InStr(excludeSheets, "|" & ws.Name & "|") = 0 Then
  
    ws.PageSetup.FirstPage.LeftHeader.Picture.Filename = _
        "S:\desktop\xxxx.png"
    
    ws.PageSetup.FirstPage.RightHeader.Picture.Filename = _
        "S:\desktop\xx.png"
        Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ws.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .Zoom = 100
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = "&G"
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = "&G"
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ws.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "add free text here"
   
    
    'Ensure Pagebreaks don't show
    ws.DisplayPageBreaks = False
        
 
    
End If

Next ws
End With
Sheets("SheetA").Select

OutPut = MsgBox("Headers & Footers added", vbInformation, "Information")
End Sub
```